# Make vim see # as a part of a word

Tags: vim, autocomplete

For example, suppose we have a file with three lines:

```
#capitalism
caps
#cap
```

if the cursor is after #cap and I press c-n, I want it autocomplete to #captalism instead of offering me two options.

Answer (score 2):

What belongs to a *word* is controlled via the `'iskeyword'` option. To do this just for the current file:

```
:setlocal iskeyword+=#
```

If this is for a particular *filetype*, put this into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim`. To change the global default, use `:set` in your `~/.vimrc`, but be warned that this can affect syntax highlighting.